# Maximum of a Polynomial on the Unit Disc

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, maximum-principle

Let $\mathbb D = \{z \in \mathbb C : \vert z \vert < 1\}$ and $\mathcal P$ the set of all polynomials with

$$ P(z) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i z^i, \ a_n \neq 0,\ n \in \mathbb N.$$

Then for every $P \in \mathcal P$ it holds that $\max_{z \in \partial \mathbb D} \vert P(z) \vert > 1$.

Let $P \in \mathcal P$. Using the maximum principle I achieved

$$ \max_{z \in \partial \mathbb D} \vert P(z) \vert = \max_{z \in \overline{\mathbb D}} \vert P(z) \vert \geq \vert P(0) \vert = 1.$$

Further I know that 
$$ \left\vert \frac{P(z)}{a_n z^n} \right\vert \to 1 \quad \text{for} \quad \vert z \vert \to \infty.$$

Hence there is a $r > 0$ with $\vert P(z) \vert \geq \frac 1 2 \vert a_n \vert \vert z \vert^n$ for all $\vert z \vert \geq r$. Hence there exists a $R > 0$ with $$\vert P(z) \vert > \vert P(0) \vert = 1 \quad \text{for all} \quad \vert z \vert = R.$$

But how can I deduce that $R = 1$ or get that $\max_{z \in \partial \mathbb D} \vert P(z) \vert > 1$ from the first equation? I think I am missing some details. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you recall the open mapping theorem? (Or the maximum principle in its local form?)

Comment: Sorry, there was a "1" missing. I edited it. Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: Presumably you mean to have $a_i z^i$?

Comment: Sorry, another typo. @DanielFischer, I really don't see how this could help me :/

Comment: Is $P$ a constant function?

Comment: Ok you want to prove that $\max_{|z| = 1} |P(z)| > 1$, not that $\max_{|z| = 1} |P(z)| \ge 1$. As Daniel said, $\mathbb{D}$ is open, and by the open mapping theorem $P(\mathbb{D})$ is open.

Comment: And how can I use that? I would appreciate an answer with some details since I am not so used to function theory and the common arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this (open mapping theorem is a good one to have
in your toolbox), here is an elementary way:

We can write $P(z) = 1+z^k g(z)$, where $g$ is a polynomial and $g(0) \neq 0$.

Let $g(0) = r e^{i \theta}$.

Let $\phi(t) = |P(t e^{-i { \theta \over k}})|$, with $t \ge 0$ and note that
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(t) &=& | 1 + t^k {\overline{g(0)} \over |g(0)|} g(t e^{-i { \theta \over k}}) | \\
&=& | 1 + t^k {\overline{g(0)} \over |g(0)|} (g(0)+g(t e^{-i { \theta \over k}})-g(0) ) | \\
&=&
| 1 + t^k |g(0)| + t^k {\overline{g(0)} \over |g(0)|} ( g(t e^{-i { \theta \over k}})-g(0) ) | \\
&\ge& 1 + t^k |g(0)| - t^k |{\overline{g(0)} \over |g(0)|}| |g(t e^{-i { \theta \over k}})-g(0)|
\end{eqnarray}
By continuity, we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that if $t \in [0,\delta)$
then $|{\overline{g(0)} \over |g(0)|}| |g(t e^{-i { \theta \over k}})-g(0)| < {1 \over 2} |g(0)|$, and so
$\phi(t) \ge 1 + {1 \over 2} t^k |g(0)| $. In particular, we can choose $t$
such that $t e^{-i { \theta \over k}}$ lies in the unit disc, and so
$|P(t e^{-i { \theta \over k}})| > 1$.

Comment: Thank you! But now I'm curious how to sie the open mapping theorem.

Comment: The open mapping theorem says that a non constant analytic function maps open sets to open sets. Hence $P(B(0,1))$ is an open set containing $1$, and from this we see that it must contain $1+ \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: Oh, that is much easier. Thank you :)

Comment: The open mapping theorem is a very powerful result.

Comment: Yes, i see. I will keep it in mind!